Apache Rewrite Rule Combine Proxy and Handler
I'm running an apache 2.4 webserver on an standard debian distribution.
I need to get content from a different application server and run it through the server-parsed handler afterwards.
To achieve that, I'm trying to combine the Flags P and H, but it doesn't work.
I had an Handler defined for the old file, like this in a Directory-Directive:
AddType text/html .html
AddHandler server-parsed .html

That did work for the files coming from the directory.
I now have a rule like this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule old/old.html http://localhost:8080/applicaton/new [QSA,P,L,H=server-parsed]

This delivers the content from the applicaton-server from localhost:8080 to the client. But it is not server-parsed.
I did also try so use AddHandler or SetHandler in a matching LocationMatch-Directive. That didn't work either.
I haven't found any documentation on using both flags P and H. Has anybody tried this before, or knows where to find documentation about those flags working together?
